# Join list of objects on linq query

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-objects, multiple-tables

I try to join list of "Users" with list of "Receivers" and create ResultClass. There may or may not be Receiver object for user. Receiver object contains list of UserIds and I want these Id:s to be replaced with correct user.

Here is example program of what I try to do and what I want.

```
class Program
{
    class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString(){return Name;}
    }

    class UserIdHolder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }

    class ReceiverTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; } //User, whos entry this is.
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserIdHolder> LinkedUserIds { get; set; } //Linked users
    }

    class ResultClass
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; } //additional data
        public ICollection<User> LinkedUsers { get; set; } //null / empty if none exists
        public override string ToString() { return User.ToString(); }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user1 = new User { Id = 1, Name = "User1" }; //Has table, with 2 linked users
        User user2 = new User { Id = 2, Name = "User2" };
        User user3 = new User { Id = 3, Name = "User3" }; //Has table, with 3 linked users
        User user4 = new User { Id = 4, Name = "User4" }; //Has table, without linked users
        User user5 = new User { Id = 5, Name = "User5" };

        ReceiverTable User1Table = new ReceiverTable
        {
            Id = 1,
            UserId = 1,
            OtherProperty = "Something for User1Table",
            LinkedUserIds = new List<UserIdHolder>
            {
                new UserIdHolder(){ Id  = 1, UserId = 2},
                new UserIdHolder(){ Id  = 2, UserId = 3}
            }
        };

        ReceiverTable User3Table = new ReceiverTable
        {
            Id = 2,
            UserId = 3,
            OtherProperty = "Something for User3Table",
            LinkedUserIds = new List<UserIdHolder>
            {
                new UserIdHolder(){ Id  = 3, UserId = 2},
                new UserIdHolder(){ Id  = 4, UserId = 4},
                new UserIdHolder(){ Id  = 5, UserId = 5}
            }
        };

        ReceiverTable User4Table = new ReceiverTable
        {
            Id = 3,
            UserId = 4,
            OtherProperty = "Something for User4Table",
            LinkedUserIds = new List<UserIdHolder>()
        };


        //"Database"
        List<User> _users = new List<User> { user1, user2, user3, user4, user5 };
        List<ReceiverTable> _receivers = new List<ReceiverTable> { User1Table, User3Table, User4Table };

        var query = from user in _users
                    join rt in _receivers on user.Id equals rt.UserId into rvTemp
                    from subRecv in rvTemp
                    from linkedUser in subRecv.LinkedUserIds
                    join u in _users on linkedUser.UserId equals u.Id into linkedUserTmp
                    select new ResultClass
                    {
                        User = user,
                        OtherProperty = subRecv.OtherProperty,
                        LinkedUsers = linkedUserTmp.ToList()
                    };

        //query should contain 5 items, all with unique User
        //if user has ReceiverTable entry, it should be added with Other property and linked users
        var uniqueUsers = query.GroupBy(q => q.User);
        if (uniqueUsers.Count() != 5)
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

So now I get 5 objects where User object is not unique. I need 5 objects, each with unique User (User 1 - 5) and other propertys set if there is any to set. So I don't understand this linq logic and I haven't found any good solutions for this problem.

To clarify, I want ResultClass object for every User in _users table.

Comment: What _specifically_ do you expect in `uniqueUsers`? What should the `Type` of that variable be?

Comment: @mjwills the part of "uniqueUsers" is only to test if the query has failed its purpose. I want to have list of ResultClass where every object has different User in User property (user1 to user5). So to answer your question, I expect uniqueUsers to be 5. Now it is 3 with this code. But the uniqueUsers variable is not the end product of this query. It is the query result that I am interested.

Comment: What would the other properties (`OtherProperty` etc) of those 5 `ResultClass` instances be?

Comment: So for ResultClass object, where User is user1, OtherProperty would be "Something for User1Table" and LinkedUsers list should containt user2 and user3. If you see User1Table variable init, you see what database contains  and how I link UserId:s. So basically I want to replace User1Table variables "UserId" properties with User objects.